# 2D array (board) shortest path with highest score

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra

I am developing a new game with an 2D array (game board). Each cell/ tile has a amount of points.

[image]

What I want to achieve is that an algorithm can find the shortest path with the highest core.

So I first implemented the Dijkstra Algorithm (source code below) to find the shortest path from start to end (red route). This works great.

My question is: How can I extend my algorithm, so it determines the shortest path with the **highest** score (so the green route).

Thank you in advance!

```
class Graph
{
    // Dictionary<Start Point, vertices>
    Dictionary<char, Dictionary<char, int>> vertices = new Dictionary<char, Dictionary<char, int>>();

    public void add_vertex(char name, Dictionary<char, int> edges)
    {
        vertices[name] = edges;
    }

    public List<char> shortest_path(char start, char finish)
    {
        var previous = new Dictionary<char, char>();
        var distances = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        var nodes = new List<char>();

        List<char> path = null;

        foreach (var vertex in vertices)
        {
            if (vertex.Key == start)
            {
                distances[vertex.Key] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                distances[vertex.Key] = int.MaxValue;
            }

            nodes.Add(vertex.Key);
        }

        while (nodes.Count != 0)
        {
            nodes.Sort((x, y) => distances[x] - distances[y]);

            var smallest = nodes[0];
            nodes.Remove(smallest);

            if (smallest == finish)
            {
                path = new List<char>();
                while (previous.ContainsKey(smallest))
                {
                    path.Add(smallest);
                    smallest = previous[smallest];
                }

                break;
            }

            if (distances[smallest] == int.MaxValue)
            {
                break;
            }

            foreach (var neighbor in vertices[smallest])
            {
                var alt = distances[smallest] + neighbor.Value;
                if (alt < distances[neighbor.Key])
                {
                    distances[neighbor.Key] = alt;
                    previous[neighbor.Key] = smallest;
                }
            }
        }

        return path;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I already tried something like this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
  foreach (var neighbour in _vertices[smallest])
  {
      // The variable alt is the length of the path from the root node to the neighbor node if it were to go through _vertices[smallest].
      var alt = pointInfos[smallest].Distance + neighbour.Value.Distance;
      var altScore = pointInfos[smallest].Points + neighbour.Value.Points;
      if (alt <= pointInfos[neighbour.Key].Distance && altScore > pointInfos[neighbour.Key].Points) // A shorter path with higher points to neighbour has been found
      {
          pointInfos[neighbour.Key] = new PointInfo(alt, altScore);
          previous[neighbour.Key] = smallest;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Your green path is not the shortest.

Comment: That's right: It is the shortest path with the highest score! That's what I want to achieve...

Comment: When you have two criteria you have to order them correctly. Are you saying you want the highest score first, then in the event of two paths having the same score, choose the shortest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to give a full enhanced answer here, but I think I can give you a good tip on how to achieve this.

What you will need to do is use your scores in the cells as edge lengths on your graph. Going to the next cell will take you 1 or 100 steps.

It will be easier to implement a longest path algorithm, because you want to maximize the score. Problem is that it will then go over the whole board instead.

[image]

So what you need is a negative cost on going via the simple route, so it will try to go over 100, but not over the rest of the negative cells.

[image]

You could also do this with the shortest path algorithm, but then you need to invert your scores so it can go over the shortest path with the lowest score.

[image]

So don't look at absolute lengths of your algorithm, but use the values as length to cross. I hope this helps and will get you to a nice algorithm in the end.